# Hide/show options leaving parent-node showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, show-hide

I am building a web page dynamically from XML that is the result of an Ajax query.  I would like the children divs of each main `question` div to be hidden when clicked but the main `query` div to remain shown.  The children divs should be shown again when the `query` div is clicked.

```
<questionBank title="How Much Do You Know About Sports?">
<question name="Sports Balls">
    <picture>xml.jp</picture>
    <details>
        <query marks="3" bonus="yes">What sport uses an oval ball?</query>
        <chapter>1</chapter>
        <hint></hint>
    </details>
    <options>
        <opt>Basketball</opt>
        <opt>Football</opt>
        <opt>Soccer</opt>
        <opt>Baseball</opt>
    </options>
    <answer>
        <correct>b</correct>
        <description>All other are incorrect</description>
    </answer>
    <profile>This question shows the the size of a certain sports ball.</profile>
</question>
```

Here's the html and script (don't mind the counts that is for something else:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script>
    var n = 1;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        mycount = 0;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "a1q3.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: parseXML
        });
    });

    function parseXML(xml) {
        $("#main").append("<div class='namestyle'>" + $(xml).find("questionBank").attr("title") + "</div>");
        $(xml).find("question").each(function() {
            $("#main").append("<div class='namestyle1'>" + $(this).attr("name") + "</div><br>");
            $("#main").append("<div class='bstyle'>" + $(this).find("query").text() + "</div><br>");
            $(this).find("opt").each(function() {
                $("#main").append($(this).text() + "<br>");
            });
        });
    };
 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <section id="main"></section>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Left out the css didn't think it was needed, just need to have the <'opts'> hidden and then when <'query'>/question is clicked the  to show and vice versa (not just one tie as many as the user wants). Here's the css for styling:

```
    <style>
 body {
    background: black; color: white;
     } 
.namestyle {
     font-size: 1.5em; color: orange;text-align: center; font-weight: bold; 
    }
.namestyle1 {
    font-size: 1.25em; color: orange; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; 
    }   
.bstyle {
    font-size: 1em; background: orange; text-align: center; color: black; padding: 5px; border-radius: 10px; 
    font-weight: bold;
    }
.bstyle2 {
    font-size: 1.5em; background: orange; color: white; padding: 5px; border-radius: 10px;
    }
.list {
    border-radius: 20px; background: rgba(100%, 0%, 0%, .5); color: black;    padding: 10px; 
    }
    </style>
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is very unclear.  "I need my query xml tag to continue to show whether hidden or not" is nonsensical.

Comment: sorry cleared that up i have multiple questions three in the xml database about sports I've got everything to view properly i just need to be able to hide/show the options like basketball, soccer, football, baseball whenever I click on the question above it.

Comment: This is still unclear.  You don't have an "xml tag called query" and your code is badly formatted.  You're handicapping yourself by making it necessary for people to put in extra effort just to understand what you're asking

Comment: the tag is right under details:
 // <query marks="3" bonus="yes">What sport uses an oval ball </query> 
the main thing that just needs to be looked at is the JQuery script after the function parseXML(xml); I need to take the opt tags and somehow hide the material in it

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. Without any css we have no idea what is visible or hidden. A demo in jsfiddle.net or other sandbox would be helpful

Comment: I only used css for styling but i'll add it. this is my site address btw maybe it will help understand: http://sharmnar.dev.fast.sheridanc.on.ca/assignmentOneJquery/indexA1.html